# Shell script - get specific file from git repository and print to terminal

Tags: git, bash, shell

The script I attempted is:

```
git fetch git@repository_link.git
git show v3:my_file.yaml > exported_file.txt
```

But upon execution, I get error:

```
fatal: Invalid object name 'v3-api'
```

How can I get the file and print it's content to a local one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I immediately notice that you try to `git fetch` a repository. `git fetch` is used for bringing down a branch from a remote repository after you have cloned that repository. What you were looking for is `git clone`.

`git clone git@repository_link.git`

If you want the entire file to be copied over to another file. Then I would suggest using bash's `cp` function.

For example see the following.

```
cp /some/path/file.yaml /some/other/path/output.txt
```

Another way I'm aware of (which definitely is not better than the approach above) is redirecting the output of cat to your to-be-created file.

```
cat somefile.yaml > output.txt
```

Comment: Won't the 'clone' command copy the entire directory to my pc?

Comment: Yes, would there be a problem with that? @DavidFaiz

Comment: I prefer getting only the file I need, but in case I get the entire project, this means I would need to delete it after.

Comment: Assuming you know how to get only the file you need, my answer above answers the original question. @DavidFaiz